# rstrip only working for first dictionary entry

Tags: python, dictionary

so im using rstrip to get rid of new line identifier at end of end of dictionary entries

Here's dictionary I am working with:

```
{'100': ['Smith', 'James', '66', '150\n'], '101': ['Jones', 'Linda', '62', '124\n'], '102': ['Davis', 'David', '68', '180\n'], '103': ['Miller', 'Sandra', '65', '90\n'], '104': ['Taylor', 'Paul', '72', '150\n']}
```

notice \n at the end of each

So to get rid of this I create a list of only the keys. then use of for loop to ammend each entry.

```
keys = [k for k in dictionary]

for key in keys:

    dictionary[key][3] = dictionary[key][3].rstrip('\n')
```

However when I do this the output gets rid of the first \n only for key 100, but the rest stay. Here's what the new dictionary looks like:

```
{'100': ['Smith', 'James', '66', '150'], '101': ['Jones', 'Linda', '62', '124\n'], '102': ['Davis', 'David', '68', '180\n'], '103': ['Miller', 'Sandra', '65', '90\n'], '104': ['Taylor', 'Paul', '72', '150\n']}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

the first entry is fixed perfectly but the rest stay the same. I cant figure out why the for loop doesnt run through all the keys, but only the first one :(

Comment: This works fine when I run it... I see no more `"\n"` after running your for loop. Maybe you updated some code and didn't re-run from scratch? Try initializing `dictionary = ` the value shown in your first code block again, then run the second code block and print the dict.

Comment: try `dictionary = {k:[x.rstrip() for x in v] for k,v in dictionary.items()}` and you're done, even if one of your lists has, say, 5 elements instead of 4.

Comment: or maybe just `dictionary[key][-1] = dictionary[key][-1].rstrip('\n')`

Comment: also `keys = [k for k in dictionary]` is unnecessary. Just iterate on `dictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dict.items() will make your life easy while iterating through it. But here since you only need to update values, you can use dict.values() to iterate over values
Also use index -1 to get the last element in the list

```
dictionary = {'100': ['Smith', 'James', '66', '150\n'], '101': ['Jones', 'Linda', '62', '124\n'], '102': ['Davis', 'David', '68', '180\n'], '103': ['Miller', 'Sandra', '65', '90\n'], '104': ['Taylor', 'Paul', '72', '150\n']}

for  value in dictionary.values():

    value[-1] = value[-1].rstrip('\n')

print(dictionary)
#{'100': ['Smith', 'James', '66', '150'], 
#'101': ['Jones', 'Linda', '62', '124'], 
#'102': ['Davis', 'David', '68', '180'], 
#'103': ['Miller', 'Sandra', '65', '90'],
#'104': ['Taylor', 'Paul', '72', '150']}
```

Comment: It's odd to use `.items()` when you're only using `key`; you can just do `for key in dictionary` if `value` won't be used.

Answer (score 1):

While we're all suggesting different ways to do this, note that you don't actually need to use the keys at all. The values are `list`s, so they're mutable. Thus, here's another approach:

```py
dictionary = {'100': ['Smith', 'James', '66', '150\n'], '101': ['Jones', 'Linda', '62', '124\n'], '102': ['Davis', 'David', '68', '180\n'], '103': ['Miller', 'Sandra', '65', '90\n'], '104': ['Taylor', 'Paul', '72', '150\n']}

for value in dictionary.values():
    value[-1] = value[-1].rstrip("\n")
dictionary
# {'100': ['Smith', 'James', '66', '150'], 
#  '101': ['Jones', 'Linda', '62', '124'], 
#  '102': ['Davis', 'David', '68', '180'], 
#  '103': ['Miller', 'Sandra', '65', '90'],
#  '104': ['Taylor', 'Paul', '72', '150']}
```